# generated test mask for scope data

Tags: python, scope, data-analysis

modern scopes have the ability to generate test masks from a saved signal trace. You can just say generate a mask with +-10% from the signal trace. Later you lay the following captured traces in this mask and you get the result, wether this signal matches the mask channel or not (hit of the forbidden mask).
Is there a library in python which supports the same functionallity?

Comment: I found first hints to build the needed function on my own! matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between() or pandas.DataFrame.plot.area()
I will see what i get together!

Comment: Very helpful: https://www.python-graph-gallery.com/